# Who add a ERC-20 transaction to the blockchain?

Tags: erc-20, consensus

I'm totally new in the blockchain area and this problem nearly drives me crazy !In ethereum, there is a miner who was chosen by the consensus algorithm to add a block to the blockchain. I viewed the transaction details in https://kovan.etherscan.io/ and found the miner. However, I just can't understand by whom the ERC-20 transaction  is added ? The owner of the contract ? Please tell me if you know it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some tokens you want to transfer, you send a transaction to the blockchain to do it. The transaction's received is the token's contract address, and the transaction's payload data includes instructions to (probably) call the contract's `transfer` function.

So any token owner can interact with the token contract to transfer tokens. And there are some functionalities which anyone can call, for example viewing token balances.

Once the transaction is in the blockchain, a miner picks it up and includes it in his block.

Contracts may or may not have an *owner*. By default there is no such concept as *contract owner*, so by default nobody has any special access to the contract. So if you want the concept of *owner* to a contract, you have to code it there.